# Showing HTML backwards from JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show data in tabs from a database by inserting html from js.

The problem is...I want to show the data in ascending order (Latest time first). When I create the output html called "salida" and get it from a console.log it shows in the correct order, but when I insert it in the HTML it shows backwars (Early time first).

This is the code in the .js file:

```
let salida = "";
let logs = respuesta.data;
let contenedorBitacora = "";

for (let id of ids) {
  contenedorBitacora = document.getElementById("bitacora"+ id);
  for(let log of logs){
     let dateTime = new Date(log.fecha);              
     let optionsUtc = { timeZone: "UTC", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" };
     let utcTime = dateTime.toLocaleDateString("en-GB") + " - " + dateTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", optionsUtc);
     let mensaje = utcTime + " UTC " + " - " + log.servicio + ": " + log.texto;

     salida = `
       <p>${mensaje}</p>
      `
      console.log(salida) //Shows the info. correctly
                        
      if (id === log.fase_id) {
        contenedorBitacora.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", salida) //It's inserted backwards.
      }
   }
}
```

Here you have the console.log output:

```
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:51 UTC  - SSEI: ACTIVA FASE 4</p>              
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:53 UTC  - TWR: AA</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:54 UTC  - ARO: BB</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:57 UTC  - SSEI: CC</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:59 UTC  - SSEI: DD</p>
```

And this the html:

```
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:59 UTC - SSEI: DD</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:57 UTC - SSEI: CC</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:54 UTC - ARO: BB</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:53 UTC - TWR: AA</p>
<p>02/11/2023 - 19:51 UTC - SSEI: ACTIVA FASE 4</p>
```

I want to show it in the HTML like the console.log output.

Comment: Why are you using `afterbegin`?You should try `"beforeend"`, something like: `contenedorBitacora.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", salida)`

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Good luck. Cheers:). There is one answer explaining the concept in detail. Don't forget to accept it by clicking on the gray tick mark so that it helps future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As @mandy8055 says, you are probably looking for `beforeend`, because `afterbegin` inserts not after your existing element, but after the beginning of the list of elements, meaning before your existing element.

However, you might consider avoiding `insertAdjacentHTML` altogether, instead using `createElement` to create an element, and then using `appendChild` to append it to the *parent* of your `contenedorBitacora` element. Something like this:

```
let salida;
let logs = respuesta.data;
let contenedorBitacoraParent;

for (let id of ids) {
  contenedorBitacoraParent = document.getElementById("bitacora"+ id).parentElement;
  for(let log of logs){
     let dateTime = new Date(log.fecha);              
     let optionsUtc = { timeZone: "UTC", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" };
     let utcTime = dateTime.toLocaleDateString("en-GB") + " - " + dateTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", optionsUtc);
     let mensaje = utcTime + " UTC " + " - " + log.servicio + ": " + log.texto;

     salida = document.createElement('p');
     salida.innerText = mensaje;

      console.log(salida.innerText) //Shows the info. correctly
                    
      if (id === log.fase_id) {
        contenedorBitacoraParent.appendChild(salida);
      }
   }
}
```

Now, if you do not have a container for your paragraphs (the parent is, say, `document.body`), you might consider enclosing them in a `div` with an id, and setting `contenedorBitacoraParent` (of course, you can use any name you want here; I just used that one to illustrate the use of your element's parent) directly to the `div` with `getElementById`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using beforeend solved the problem. I'm using the div and I'm going to try it with "createElement" and "appendChild.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: @CarlosVergara You're welcome. I've just found that approach to be easier to think through than directly manipulating the HTML.